# AWS Cognito Migrate User Node.js Lambda Function invoked but not behaving as expected

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I created a Migrate User Lambda function and connected it to my AWS Cognito Hosted UI.  The lambda is invoked and I see my log statements in the CloudWatch logs.  Everything seems to be working except that the hosted UI does not seem to behave as expected.  It's almost like the Lambda is not called, but I know that it is because I see the log statements.  The hosted UI always displays the "The username or password you entered is invalid", whereas I was expecting it to take the user to the Reset Password workflow.

My Node function is:

```js
const https = require('https')

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    if ( event.triggerSource == "UserMigration_Authentication" ) {


        LoginUser(event.userName, event.request.password, function(user, message){
            
            console.log("Finished LoginUser call.");
            
            if ( user ) {
                console.log("Got a valid user with userId=" + user.userId);
                
                event.response.userAttributes = {
                    "userName" : user.userName,
                    "email": user.emailAddress,
                    "email_verified": "true",
                    "picture" : user.imageUrl,
                    "family_name" : user.lastName,
                    "given_name" : user.firstName,
                    "custom:userId" : user.userId
                };
                event.response.finalUserStatus = "RESET_REQUIRED";
                event.response.messageAction = "SUPPRESS";
                event.response.desiredDeliveryMediums = "EMAIL";
                
                console.log("Done: " + JSON.stringify(event));
                
                //callback(null,event);
                context.succeed(event);
            }
            else {
                console.log("User was not found. " + message );
                callback(message, event);
            }
        });
        
    }
    else if ( event.triggerSource == "UserMigration_ForgotPassword" ) {
        
        /*
         * Check to see if the user exists.  If so, then tell cognito
         * to proceed, given the email address we looked up.
         */
     LookupUser(event.userName, function(user, message){
        
        if ( user ) {
            
                event.response.userAttributes = {
                    "email": user.emailAddress,
                    "email_verified": "true"  
                };
                event.response.messageAction = "SUPPRESS";

                console.log("Done: " + JSON.stringify(event));
                //callback(null,event);
                context.succeed(event);
        } 
        else {
            callback(message, event);
        }
        
     });
 
    }
    else {
        callback("Bad triggerSource " + event.triggerSource);
    }
};





/*
 * Lookup a user
 */
function LookupUser(userName, UserCallback) {
    
    var pathUri = "/api/user?op=or&userName=" + encodeURIComponent(userName); 
    console.log("pathUri=" + pathUri);

    var headers = {
        "x-k-Id": process.env.kmpzPublicKey,
        "x-k-Sig": process.env.kmpzSecretKey
    };
    
    var options = {
        host: "www.mydomainhere.com",
        port: 443,
        path: pathUri,
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    };    

    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {  
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            
            var user = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(user);
            
            if ( user.error ) {
                UserCallback(null, user.error.message);
            }
            else if ( user.userId ) {
                UserCallback(user, "OK");
            }
            else {
                UserCallback(null, "Unexpected response from userService.  Please contact Kompoz Customer Support.");
            }
        });
    });    
    
    req.on('error', function(e) {
        UserCallback(null, e.message);
    });    
  
    req.end();    
};



/*
 * Login a user
 */
function LoginUser(userName, userPassword, UserCallback) {
    
    var pathUri = "/api/auth/migrate?userName=" + encodeURIComponent(userName) + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(userPassword);
    console.log("pathUri=" + pathUri);

    var headers = {
        "x-k-Id": process.env.kmpzPublicKey,
        "x-k-Sig": process.env.kmpzSecretKey
    };
    
    var options = {
        host: "www.mydomainhere.com",
        port: 443,
        path: pathUri,
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers
    };    

    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {  
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            
            var user = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(user);
            
            if ( user.error ) {
                UserCallback(null, user.error.message);
            }
            else if ( user.userId ) {
                UserCallback(user, "OK");
            }
            else {
                UserCallback(null, "Unexpected response from userService.  Please contact Kompoz Customer Support.");
            }
        });
    });    
    
    req.on('error', function(e) {
        UserCallback(null, e.message);
    });    
  
    req.end();    
};
```

In CloudWatch logs, I see the response:

```js
{
    "version": "1",
    "triggerSource": "UserMigration_Authentication",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "userPoolId": "us-east-1_******",
    "userName": "exampleUser",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-unknown-unknown",
        "clientId": "2s12aui53t9a4n85orc3d3ul0u"
    },
    "request": {
        "password": "*******",
        "validationData": null,
        "userAttributes": null
    },
    "response": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "userName": "exampleUser",
            "email": "me@example.com",
            "email_verified": "true",
            "picture": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/example-s3/images/m1006-20140119-033844-p2.jpg",
            "family_name": "Smith",
            "given_name": "John",
            "custom:userId": 1006
        },
        "forceAliasCreation": null,
        "finalUserStatus": "RESET_REQUIRED",
        "messageAction": "SUPPRESS",
        "desiredDeliveryMediums": "EMAIL"
    }
}
```

Here's what I get:
[image: Login Screen]

Comment: I have the same problem: when the user is migrated with "RESET_REQUIRED", it seems that the password is not imported in Cognito, every next auth action results in a "NotAuthorizedException".
If i use the Cognito Console to force a user already imported as "RESET_REQUIRED", everything then works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Wish I could help.  Just here to say "me too".  Are you getting the HTTP/401 error?  My lambda is running as well but I can't get past the error message.  No logs in cloudwatch and no hints in cloudtrail.

### HTML/401

```
Request URL: https://******.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=**************************&redirect_uri=https://local.******.com/auth/login
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: 54.191.35.239:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
cache-control: private
content-language: en-US
content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 02 Sep 2019 04:45:17 GMT
expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC
server: Server
set-cookie: cognito-fl="W10="; Version=1; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
status: 401
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
x-amz-cognito-request-id: 18e6f6e5-6c85-4280-81ac-b90428d66202
x-application-context: application:prod:8443
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: DENY
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
:authority: ******.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com
:method: GET
:path: /login?response_type=code&client_id=************************&redirect_uri=https://local.******.com/auth/login
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=b4c1c540-6eac-4309-bd81-1ce3cc54e259; cognito-fl="W3sidGFyZ2V0UmVxdWVzdFBhdGgiOiIvbG9naW4iLCJtYXAiOnsibG9naW5FcnJvck1lc3NhZ2UiOiJUaGUgdXNlcm5hbWUgb3IgcGFzc3dvcmQgeW91IGVudGVyZWQgaXMgaW52YWxpZCJ9fV0="
dnt: 1
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://******.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=***********************&redirect_uri=https://local.******.com/auth/login
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
response_type: code
client_id: ****************
redirect_uri: https://local.******.com/auth/login
```

### Lambda response

```
{
  "version": "1",
  "triggerSource": "UserMigration_Authentication",
  "region": "us-west-2",
  "userPoolId": "us-west-2_KIcLJftsn",
  "userName": "eflyerman@gmail.com",
  "callerContext": {
    "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-unknown-unknown",
    "clientId": "**********************"
  },
  "request": {
    "password": "*********",
    "validationData": null,
    "userAttributes": null
  },
  "response": {
    "userAttributes": {
      "email_verified": true,
      "phone_number": "281******",
      "given_name": "E***e",
      "middle_name": "",
      "family_name": "S*****",
      "custom:role": "doctor|admin|",
      "custom:user_id": 528
    },
    "forceAliasCreation": null,
    "finalUserStatus": "CONFIRMED",
    "messageAction": "SUPPRESS",
    "desiredDeliveryMediums": "EMAIL"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The awsdocs github repo contains sample working code of migrate user lambda: [migrate-user](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/cognito/scenarios/lambda-triggers/functions/migrate-user.mjs).
   Note that in the end only the event is returned, the context and callback are not used in this working example.
2. Regarding the incorrect username/password issue, one possible issue could be that while setting the user pool sign-in options you have selected both User name and Email. In such cases the user pool doesn't allow to set an email for username. For this configuration the migration is allowed only when the username is a non-email string.